# Outputting to textarea from database

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to out put a database field value into a text area by doing this but it's not working.

```
<textarea name="course_id" cols=40 rows=3 value="<?php echo $row['course_id'] ; ?>"></textarea>
```

but when i use

```
<input type="text" name="course_id" value="<?php echo $row['course_id'] ; ?> ">
```

it worked well.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: That's some bizarre white space in your code

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You enter the value between textarea tags.

```
<textarea name = "course_id" cols=40  rows=3>
<?php echo $row['course_id'] ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 6):

textarea doesn't have value attribute. You have to echo in between the tags. The correct code would be:

```
<textarea name = "course_id" cols=40  rows=3 ><?php echo $row['course_id']; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: You probably should add a safeguard in just in case the database text any tags in it for example <script> or </textarea>

Answer (score 1):

**Check this out**

There is no value field for Textarea

So you need to give your value inside the `<textarea><?php echo $yourdatabaseResult;?></textarea>` tags

Answer (score 0):

**echo** your data between tags follow this step :-

```
<TextArea>
<?php echo $showdbdata; ?>
</TextArea>
```

Answer (score 0):

echo your data in `textarea` for laravel

```html
<textarea type="text" name="job_detail" class="form-control" style="width: 100%; height: 150px; ">{{  $job[0]->job_detail }}</textarea>
```