# textarea data is not showing in form - but is saving to database, anyone know why?

Tags: php, html

my form(foundation 5 html form) is saving all the fields to the database and all the fields are repopulating back into the pop up form except for the textarea data field - this field is not repopulating

I have tried adding textarea id="task_description" to the tag and some other simple things that I did not have much faith in working..and, nope, it did not work!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <label>Task Description </label>
        <textarea name="task_description"  placeholder="task details.." value="<?php echo $task->task_description; ?>" >
     </textarea>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I am wanting the text that is typed into the task_description field of my form to repopulate back into the form when selecting the row from the page listview. I am using PDO..and have bound this field just the same as all the other fields in my form. The other fields repopulate, but the task description will not - it is empty. The field data is saving to the database however.

Comment: a `textarea` does not use the `value` attribute - put the actual value between start and end textarea tags - ie: `<textarea>hello</textarea>`

Comment: textarea doesn't have a `value` attribute

Comment: change to `<textarea name="task_description"  placeholder="task details.."><?php echo $task->task_description; ?></textarea>`

Comment: **echo** data in between TextArea tag [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296405/outputting-to-textarea-from-database/56240879#56240879)

Answer (score 0):

`textarea` doesn't have a value, it has content. You probably want this

```
<textarea name="task_description"  placeholder="task details.." >
    <?php echo $task->task_description; ?>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `<input>` with `<textarea>`. Inputs have values, whereas textareas use the innerText as a "value". You would want to change your code to this:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <label>Task Description </label>
    <textarea name="task_description"  placeholder="task details..">
      <?php echo $task->task_description; ?>
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hooray! that works and thank you! i do see what you were saying about adding the value to the tag and have made note not to do that in the future!